# Put parentheses around sold items in Excel Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to add parentheses to several columns in excel that will show items sold and will be subtracted from the finals column. Not sure what the formula would be. [image]

Comment: Do you really want to subtract their value or just not include them in the sum? The first would return 56.50 in the paid column and the second 58.50.

Comment: @ScottCraner my fault for not adding that I was looking for a formula.

Comment: Unless the values are in different cells, a formula cannot change the value of itself.  But you can do this with conditional formatting to display a false negative.  Then use sumifs() based on the sold column being ="" for your totals.

Comment: @ScottCraner do you know what my sumif statement would be for the categories?

Comment: for your Paid column =SUMIF(F2:F8,">0",B2:B8)`

Comment: @ScottCraner seems like that is only giving me my total amount sold for paid, and not subtracting it from B11. It should subtract from B11, then I should be able to do C11, E11,F11, and G11.